# Mathematica Manipulate[] slider initial position

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

the initial position of a slider when using the Manipulate[] command is always the left side. Is there an option to set a different position at which the slider is positioned when the notebook is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation page for Manipulate carefully. Example:

```
Manipulate[Plot[3*x + a, {x, -2, 2}], {{a, 2}, 1, 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the usual {a, 0, 10}, replace with {{a,5},0,10} to initialize a.